# Apps script wait till formula finishes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

My spreadsheet runs app-script that sends range values in an email.

I use sleep 15 sec, to avoid sending the mail before the simple formula finishes.

Nevertheless, the mail is sometimes sent too soon.

The mail is sent async, so I don't care about the time the script runs.

How do you run wait-notify for app-script? How can I send the email only after the formula finishes?

[image]

Comment: `Try SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. I'm not sure if this will help since I never use formulas.  My other answer would be do the calculation without formulas and then you will know when you are done.

Comment: Hi there @EladBenda! If the approach commented by @MetaMan is not valid in your scenario, please share your code and some use cases so we all can take a look and help you.